# Output of gdal2tiles not visible on map

Tags: python, gis, gdal, tile

I use [gdal2Tiles project](https://pypi.org/project/gdal2tiles/) to tile a .tif image from a Python script runing on AWS Lambda.
The tiles are created but it doesn't seem to work correctly because the image is not visible on the map.

If I compare with the output from the programm [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/), which is doing the job successfully, the name of the folder are the same **BUT the name of the tiles are different**.

The call I do in the python script is the following:

```
gdal2tiles.generate_tiles(input_file, f"output_folder", nb_processes=1, zoom='24-27')
```

Can you see what is missing in the function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extent in the generated html file (openlayers) is incorrect. That's why I could not see the tiles on the map.